# Calculate time taken by reducers hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a MapReduce job in Hadoop 2.7.3 in a single node cluster. How do I calculate the time taken by the map and reduce tasks of this job?

**SOLVED**
In case it helps anyone who views this question or faces a similar problem.
Thanks to @Shubham's answer and a little research I did:

1. Job tracker has been removed in hadoop 2. It has been split into resource manager and application master.
2. To access the Resource manager, type in the URL in your browser "http://localhost:8088"
3. To access the Job History Server (to view statistics about the applications and jobs that have been completed) type in the URL in your browser "http://localhost:19888"

You could encounter an error when trying to access the Job History Server. It may show that there is no history for the application. In that case follow these steps:

1. Change the bashrc file

Steps:

```
i. In your terminal, type "nano ~/.bashrc"
ii. Now in this file, where the other hadoop variables are written add the line
    export HADOOP_CONFIG_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
iii. Exit out of nano and save the file.
iv. Run the command "source ~/.bashrc"
```

1. To start the job history server

Steps:

```
i. Run the command in your terminal
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONFIG_DIR start historyserver
ii. Then run the command 
    jps
You should be able to see the "JobHistoryServer" in the list
iii. Now run the command
netstat -ntlp | grep 19888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit resource manager's web UI(http://rm_http_address_host:port/). Typically the web port is 8088. You can hit http://resourcemanager_host:8088/ for this.
There you will find the link for all the applications that are in various states like STARTED, RUNNING, FAILED, SUCCEEDED etc
Clicking on each application's link will give you all the statistics(like number of containers(mappers/reducers in case of mapreduce), memory/Vcores used, running time and a lot more stats) about that yarn job.

And a lot many stats are exposed by **ResourceManager REST API’s.** Find them here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html

Comment: The web UI closes after the job get completed. Is there any way I can get the info (maybe in some log file) which I can access after the job is completed

Comment: @alpha How are you submitting the job to the cluster?

Comment: I am using Hadoop streaming with Python currently, but I plan to switch to writing Java codes. @Shubham

Comment: @alpha ok. Just get the hadoop single node cluster up and running on your system and then submit jobs to it using command line or whatever mechanism. Then, even if a job is completed, the web UI will not close as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the jobtracker (Runs on port 50030 by default) and check the job details. It shows the counters for Map time and reduce time. Moreover if you are interested in individual tasks you can follow link "Analyse This Job" that shows best and worst performing tasks.

Comment: Can I still get the info after the job has been completed?

Comment: As long as you your job tracker maintains history, you should be able to see this info.  I am not sure though about the conifugration that controls the history.